# Remote mysql query on xampp server

Tags: mysql, xampp

Hey, I've got a website running at a webhotel with it's own sql server etc, but I've also got a mysql server running from xampp on a server at my home. I've searched around a lot and managed to connect to the mysql server from other computers on the lan by adding bind-address=0.0.0.0 in the my.ini file.

But on my remote webserver I get this error when trying to connect to it

```
Warning: mysql_connect() [function.mysql-connect]: Lost connection to MySQL server at 'reading initial communication packet', system error: 113 in /home/content/26/6794026/html/b3/db.php on line 2
Lost connection to MySQL server at 'reading initial communication packet', system error: 113
```

or

```
Warning: mysql_connect() [function.mysql-connect]: Can't connect to MySQL server on '<ip>' (4) in /home/content/26/6794026/html/b3/db.php on line 2
Can't connect to MySQL server on '<ip>' (4)
```

So I was wondering how I could configure the xampp-mysql server to allow connections from this server. I've got ports forwarded and proper user set up.

This is only for retrieving some numbers every now and then. From programs running on that server.

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

If you're connecting from a remote webserver and having this problem, but it works fine on the LAN, the problem is almost certainly your firewall or router. I would suggest going into your router settings and mapping port 3306 to the machine running MySQL. (You could also set said machine in the DMZ, but I would note that this is a security risk.)

It's not a MySQL configuration issue (probably) because the machines on your LAN can connect just fine. Similarly, if MySQL wasn't listening on the worldwide IP, you wouldn't be getting this far. So, your router/firewall is almost certainly the culprit.

Comment: I don't think so, I've got ports forwarded correctly, and tried with firewall turned off as well. Other programs function correctly over the internet on it.

Comment: Bah. Then I'm out of ideas...sorry. :(

Comment: The webserver in question is a GoDaddy, I know they don't support using their mysql server from remote, but do they also perhaps block mysql requests in the other direction? I searched a bit and found some comments which would suggest that maybe they did, but I'm not sure. I guess I'll go ask them instead next.